# How to pause and play android Native Music Player

Tags: android

I'll Play some notification alerts from my app.. At the time system should pause the music running in the device. For that i'm sending Broadcast event to pause the media.

```
    Intent audioIntent = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand.pause");
    MYActivity.sendBroadcast(audioIntent);
```

This code is only working and pausing the Google Play Music and Default Music Player.. But this code is not working for Poweramp and VLC.. Kindly post your solution..

Comment: Kindly post the comment Those who are degrading my question...

Answer (score -2):

```
 You really should supply the code you have written for the broadcast, this is a very hard question to answer without your code... Something like this is what most people use:

Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "pause");
YourApplicationClass.this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: I've used these lines only... this lines will work only for Default Players. Not Poweramp or vlc.. Checked moretime...